# passing in pointers as arguments to get string length

Tags: c, arrays, string, function, pointers

I am playing with pointers in the K&R book and I wrote this program that swaps integers and measures the length of a string with a pointer. The first part works but my string length function does nothing. The program compiles and runs the first part and then the program stops responding.

```
    #include <stdio.h>

extern int a2 = 4;
extern int b2 = 5;

void swap(int *px, int *py);
int strlen2(char *s);
//int printLabel(char *thelabel, char newliner);

//int printLabel(char *thelabel, char newliner)
//{
//        int stringlength1=(strlen2(thelabel));
//  return stringlength1;
//}

void swap(int *px, int *py)  /* interchange *px and *py */
   {
       int temp;
       temp = *px;
       *px = *py;
       *py = temp;
   }

int strlen2(char *s)
   {
       int n;
       for (n = 0; *s != '\0', s++;)
           n++;
       return n;
   }

int main()
{
int a=4;
int b=5;
char newliner = '\n';
swap(&a,&b);
swap(&a2,&b2);
printf("%d",a);
printf("%c",newliner);
printf("%d",b);
printf("%c",newliner);
printf("%d",a2);
printf("%c",newliner);
printf("%d",b2);
printf("%c",newliner);
char sumstring[]="boo";
char *labelPtr;
labelPtr = sumstring;
int length = strlen2(labelPtr);
printf("%d",length);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Also, try something like printf("%d\n", a); rather than the two printf lines.  Also you could collapse statements like printf("%d\n%d\n%d\n", a, b, a2) and so on.

Comment: Minor: Better to use type `size_t`: `size_t strlen2(char *s) { size_t n; ...` and `size_t length ... printf("%zu",length);`

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that this:

```
for (n = 0; *s != '\0', s++;)
```

is a semi-infinite loop.  It checks for the terminating NUL, but then it ignores the result of that comparison and increements s, continuing the loop if it is non-null.  Once it gets past the end of the string, the result is undefined behavior, but its likely to either loop forever or crash.

You probably meant

```
for (n = 0; *s != '\0'; s++)
```

Comment: Very strange. In the book, that's how it was shown. Thanks. That fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

In the for loop, the second expression is usually a condition, in your case *s != '\0'.
The 3rd expression is the increment, where you are supposed to increment the s pointer.

This is working fine:

```
int strlen2(char *s)
{
    int n;

    for (n = 0; *s != '\0'; s++)
        n++;

    return n;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

looks like a typo in the code. shouldn't this line be:

```
for (n = 0; *s != '\0'; s++)
```

instead of

```
for (n = 0; *s != '\0', s++;)
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with the following:

```
int strlen2(char *s)
   {
       int n = 0;
       while(s[n] != '\0')
          ++n;
       return n;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

In this for statmenet

```
for (n = 0; *s != '\0', s++;)
```

in the condition part there is used the comma operator

```
*s != '\0', s++
```

Its results is the value of the last subexpression that is of `s++`. As pointer s is not equal to 0 then you get at least very long sycle.

I think you meant instead

```
for (n = 0; *s != '\0'; s++ )
```